How to fix my Peaks.js component which works with direct render but not inside a page
I have a React web app using Peaks.js. When I route straight to my AudioWaveForm component through a BrowserRouter route, it works fine, but when I include it in an empty component it breaks. It still shows the audio, and I can play it with keyboard, but clicking on it with mouse blinks the play-line where I clicked, then immediately moves to the very start and then dissappears.
On the working BrowserRouter route, if I prepend my backend url using an env variable (not needed since I have react proxy set), it breaks the waveform for some reason. If I change the empty component to not include the env variable though, it still is broken.
Working Waveform Route
{
    path: '/waveform',
    element: <AudioWaveform audioFile={'media/song_files/test.mp3'} />
  },

Broken Waveform Route
{
    path: '/waveform',
    element: <AudioWaveform audioFile={`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKAPI}/media/song_files/test.mp3`} />
  },
 

EmptyComponent.tsx (Broken)
const AnalysisPage = () => {
 return (
<div className='w-full h-full'>
    <AudioWaveform audioFile={'/media/song_files/test.mp3`}/>
  </div>
    
  )
} 

export default AnalysisPage


AudioWaveForm.tsx
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import Peaks from 'peaks.js';
import type { PeaksInstance } from "peaks.js";

interface AudioWaveformProps {
    audioFile: string | File;
    timestamp?: number | null
}

const AudioWaveform: React.FC<AudioWaveformProps> = ({ audioFile,  timestamp=null }) => {

    const zoomViewRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const overviewRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null); 
    const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | null>(null);
    const peaksInstance = useRef<PeaksInstance | null>(null);

    const playFromTimestamp = (timestamp: number) => {
      if (audioRef.current) {
        audioRef.current.currentTime = timestamp;
        peaksInstance.current?.player.seek(timestamp);
        if (audioRef.current.paused) {
          audioRef.current.play();
        }
      }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      if (timestamp) {
        playFromTimestamp(timestamp);
      }
    }, [timestamp]);

    // initialize peaks.js
    useEffect(() => {
        if (audioRef.current && zoomViewRef.current && overviewRef.current) {
            const audioContext = new AudioContext();
      
            const options = {
              zoomview: {
                container: zoomViewRef.current,
                showPlayheadTime: true,
              },
              overview: {
                container: overviewRef.current,
              },
              mediaElement: audioRef.current,
              webAudio: {
                audioContext: audioContext,
                scale: 128,
                multiChannel: false,
              },
            };
      
            Peaks.init(options, function (err, peaks) {
              if (err) {
                console.error('Error initializing Peaks.js:', err);
              } else {
                if (peaks) {
                  peaksInstance.current = peaks;

                  peaks.on('zoomview.click', (event) => {
                    if (audioRef.current) {
                      audioRef.current.currentTime = event.time;
                    }
                  });

                } else {
                  console.error('Error: Peaks is undefined')
                }
                
              }
            });

            return () => {
              if (peaksInstance.current) {
                peaksInstance.current.destroy();
                peaksInstance.current = null;
              }
          };
        }
        
    }, []);

    // Audio playback with space key
    useEffect(() => {
      const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (event.code === "Space" && audioRef.current) {
          event.preventDefault();
      
          const currentTime = peaksInstance.current?.player.getCurrentTime();
          if (currentTime !== undefined) {
            audioRef.current.currentTime = currentTime; 
            if (audioRef.current.paused) {
              audioRef.current.play();
            } else {
              audioRef.current.pause();
            }
          }
        }
      };
  
      document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
      };
    }, []);


    
  return (
    <div className='w-full h-full'>
        <div className='w-full h-1/2' ref={zoomViewRef}></div>
        <div className='w-full h-1/2' ref={overviewRef}></div>
        <audio
          ref={audioRef} 
          src={typeof audioFile === "string" ? audioFile : URL.createObjectURL(audioFile)}
        ></audio>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AudioWaveform


Do you have a Codesandbox of this? Would be easier to check what's wrong? Without the running code I can only guess what could be the problem. I would check the useEffect and try to move the peaksInstance.current.destroy callback to the end of the hook. Are there any error messages in the browser console?
